# I'm trying to use this "If else" condition without using "System...println"

Tags: java, if-statement

Hey guys I'm completely new to Java/programming and I need help with one of my assignments. I'm suppose to use a `if else` condition without using `System.out.println()` or main method.

Here's the question "The card ranks inside the hand are given as characters inside the string, but sometimes it would be more convenient to handle these ranks as numerical values from 2 to 14. The spot cards from two to ten have their numerical values, and the face cards jack, queen, king and ace have the values of 11, 12, 13 and 14, respectively. Write a method int `getRank(char c)` that returns the numerical value of the card given as the character parameter c. For example, when called with argument `Q`, this method would return 12. You must write this method as an if-else ladder."

So far I created a program but I can't seem to get it to return `char c = str.charAt(2);` if `char c` is 4 in the String.

I've posted an image of my code and i would really appreciate the help. If there is anything I should redo or not do please tell me. I want to learn as much as I can and not just get by my course out of pure luck. I really do want to succeed in the computer science field. Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Comment: java & javascript not same

Comment: It would be good if you paste your code here not image

Comment: Posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: An if-else ladder would have a whole lot of comparisons in it, like `if (c == 'A')`, and later `else if (c == '2')` and still later `else if (c == '3')` and so on.  The single quote marks are important because these are characters, not numbers.

Comment: Surely you can see that the task is to write a method `int getRank(char c)`, whereas your `getRank` has neither a parameter nor the correct result type.

Comment: btw, you have duplicate in code `char e = ...` & `char d = ...`

Comment: My apologizes to everyone here, I will make note of that the next time i post a question. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all as pointed out by @brk, java and javascript are not the same. They do have similar syntax but are two completely different programming languages.

Regarding your question, if we assume 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T for numerical cards and J,Q,K,A for face cards, then the code would look like:

```
public static int getRank(char c){
    if(c=='2'){
        return 2;
    }else if(c=='3'){
        return 3;
    }else if(c=='4'){
        return 4;
    }else if(c=='5'){
        return 5;
    }else if(c=='6'){
        return 6;
    }else if(c=='7'){
        return 7;
    }else if(c=='8'){
        return 8;
    }else if(c=='9'){
        return 9;
    }else if(c=='T'){
        return 10;
    }else if(c=='J'){
        return 11;
    }else if(c=='Q'){
        return 12;
    }else if(c=='K'){
        return 13;
    }else if(c=='A'){
        return 14;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

To call the function you can either call it as
`System.out.println("Numerical value of Queen = " + getRank('Q'));`
or
store it in a variable like
`int value = getRank('A');`

Comment: Thank you for your code! It helps a lot as It's much easier for me to understand what i did wrong and how to approach situations. I do have a question about your code though, when I ran your code (I use BlueJ as my program for Java.) I keep getting a return value of -1. For example, if c==2 and i input 2, shouldn't my return be 2 not -1?

Comment: Are you sure you're giving the parameter input as '2' and not 2? '2' will be treated as a char value whereas 2 will be treated as an int value.